# ARCore OpenGL ES Moving Object using onScroll

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I'm attempting to add in the moving of objects around with single finger scrolling. (See Google AR Stickers for example) I'm using native ARCore/OpenGL based originally off the ARCore examples. When you slide 1 finger, I want to move the object in 3D space along the X and Z axes.

I can easily create the movement using Translation, however, it performs the movement based on the original camera orientation. If you physically move the phone/camera a few lateral steps, the finger movements no longer match what a user would expect.

So I changed up my code and mapped the finger distanceX and distanceY that is swiped to affect X and Z coordinates depending on the angle of change from the original camera starting point to the current camera point.

The issue that I'm running into is determining the angle at which the camera has been moved. I've been looking at the value from the Camera View matrix:

```
camera.getViewMatrix(viewmtx, 0);
```

But the X, Y, and Z coordinates always say 0. I'm assuming this is because it's always making the camera the origin? Does anyone know of a way to calculate the angle of rotation of a camera from a 3D object using the ARCore/OpenGL ES libraries? The red angle in the illustration below (from top-down perspective) is what I'm trying to get. Sorry for the crude drawing:

[image]

Here's my code for your reference:

```
// Handle Gestures - Single touch for Translation and Placement
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
{
  @Override
  public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
  {
    onSingleTap(e);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
  {
    if (e2.getPointerCount() == 1 && ...)
    {
      double angle = findCameraAngleFromOrigin();
      double speed = 0.005d;

      if (angle / 90d < 1) //Quadrant 1
      {
        double transX = -(distanceY * (angle / 90d)) + (distanceX * ((90d - angle) / 90d));
        double transY = (distanceY * ((90d - angle) / 90d)) + (distanceX * (angle / 90d));
        mTranslationX.set(mTranslationX.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationX.get(mTranslationX.size() - 1) + (transX * -speed)));
        mTranslationZ.set(mTranslationZ.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationZ.get(mTranslationZ.size() - 1) + (transY * -speed)));
      }
      else if (angle / 90d < 2) //Quadrant 2
      {
        angle -= 90d;
        double transX = (distanceX * (angle / 90d)) + (distanceY * ((90d - angle) / 90d));
        double transY = (-distanceX * ((90d - angle) / 90d)) + (distanceY * (angle / 90d));
        mTranslationX.set(mTranslationX.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationX.get(mTranslationX.size() - 1) + (transX * speed)));
        mTranslationZ.set(mTranslationZ.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationZ.get(mTranslationZ.size() - 1) + (transY * speed)));
      }
      else if (angle / 90d < 3) //Quadrant 3
      {
        angle -= 180d;
        double transX = (distanceY * (angle / 90d)) + (-distanceX * ((90d - angle) / 90d));
        double transY = (-distanceY * ((90d - angle) / 90d)) + (-distanceX * (angle / 90d));
        mTranslationX.set(mTranslationX.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationX.get(mTranslationX.size() - 1) + (transX * -speed)));
        mTranslationZ.set(mTranslationZ.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationZ.get(mTranslationZ.size() - 1) + (transY * -speed)));
      }
      else  //Quadrant 4
      {
        angle -= 270d;
        double transX = (-distanceX * (angle / 90d)) + (-distanceY * ((90d - angle) / 90d));
        double transY = (distanceX * ((90d - angle) / 90d)) + (-distanceY * (angle / 90d));
        mTranslationX.set(mTranslationX.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationX.get(mTranslationX.size() - 1) + (transX * speed)));
        mTranslationZ.set(mTranslationZ.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationZ.get(mTranslationZ.size() - 1) + (transY * speed)));
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Update to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out how to find the distance from the camera points, but I was able to at least find the difference in the phone's rotation, which is closer. I accomplished it by the code below. I'm still not happy with the results, so I'll post updates later on when I find a more effective solution.

```
private double getDegree(double value1, double value2)
{
    double firstAngle = value1 * 90;
    double secondAngle = value2 * 90;
    if (secondAngle >= 0 && firstAngle >= 0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "FIRST QUADRANT");
        return firstAngle; // first quadrant
    }
    else if (secondAngle < 0 && firstAngle >= 0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "SECOND QUADRANT");
        return 90 + (90 - firstAngle); //second quadrant
    }
    else if (secondAngle < 0 && firstAngle < 0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "THIRD QUADRANT");
        return 180 - firstAngle; //third quadrant
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "FOURTH QUADRANT");
        return 270 + (90 + firstAngle); //fourth quadrant
    }
}

private double findCameraAngleFromOrigin()
{
    double angle = getDegree(mCurrentCameraMatrix[2], mCurrentCameraMatrix[0]) - getDegree(mOriginCameraMatrix[2], mOriginCameraMatrix[0]);
    if (angle < 0)
        return angle + 360;
    return angle;
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    ...
    //When creating a new object
    Anchor anchor = hit.createAnchor();
    mAnchors.add(anchor);
    camera.getDisplayOrientedPose().toMatrix( mOriginCameraMatrix, 0);

    //During each draw frame
    camera.getDisplayOrientedPose().toMatrix( mCurrentCameraMatrix, 0);

    int ac = 0;
    for (Anchor anchor : mAnchors)
    {
      if (anchor.getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING)
      {
        continue;
      }
      // Get the current pose of an Anchor in world space. The Anchor pose is updated
      // during calls to session.update() as ARCore refines its estimate of the world.
      anchor.getPose().toMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, 0);

      // Update and draw the model
      if (mModelSet)
      {
        if (mScaleFactors.size() <= ac)
        {
          mScaleFactors.add(1.0f);
        }
        if (mRotationThetas.size() <= ac)
        {
          mRotationThetas.add(0.0f);
        }
        if (mTranslationX.size() <= ac)
        {
          mTranslationX.add(viewmtx[3]);
        }
        if (mTranslationZ.size() <= ac)
        {
          mTranslationZ.add(viewmtx[11]);
        }

        translateMatrix(mTranslationX.get(ac), 0, mTranslationZ.get(ac));
        rotateYAxisMatrix(mRotationThetas.get(ac));

        ObjectRenderer virtualObject = mVirtualObjects.get(mAnchorReferences.get(ac));
        virtualObject.updateModelMatrix(mAnchorMatrix, mScaleFactors.get(ac));
        virtualObject.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);
      }
      ac++;
    }
}
```

This is kind of hard to track, so I'll probably just post the entire class once I feel more comfortable with the implementation and code cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloArActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private static final String TAG = HelloArActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Rendering. The Renderers are created here, and initialized when the GL surface is created.
    private GLSurfaceView surfaceView;

    private boolean installRequested;

    private Session session;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private Snackbar messageSnackbar;
    private DisplayRotationHelper displayRotationHelper;

    private final BackgroundRenderer backgroundRenderer = new BackgroundRenderer();
    private final ObjectRenderer virtualObject = new ObjectRenderer();
    private final ObjectRenderer virtualObjectShadow = new ObjectRenderer();
    private final PlaneRenderer planeRenderer = new PlaneRenderer();
    private final PointCloudRenderer pointCloud = new PointCloudRenderer();
    private int mCurrent = -1;
    private final List<ObjectRenderer> mVirtualObjects = new ArrayList<ObjectRenderer>();

    // Temporary matrix allocated here to reduce number of allocations for each frame.
    private final float[] anchorMatrix = new float[16];
    //Rotation, Moving, & Scaling
    private final List<Float> mRotationThetas = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private RotationGestureDetector mRotationDetector;
    private final List<Float> mScaleFactors = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private final List<Float> mTranslationX = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private final List<Float> mTranslationZ = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private final float[] mOriginCameraMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mCurrentCameraMatrix = new float[16];
    private boolean mModelSet = false;

    // Tap handling and UI.
    private final ArrayBlockingQueue<MotionEvent> mQueuedSingleTaps = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(16);
    private final ArrayList<Anchor> mAnchors = new ArrayList<>();
    // Tap handling and UI.
    private final ArrayBlockingQueue<MotionEvent> queuedSingleTaps = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(16);
    private final List<Integer> mAnchorReferences = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
        displayRotationHelper = new DisplayRotationHelper(/*context=*/ this);
//Handle Gestures - Multitouch for Scaling and Rotation
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                if (mScaleFactors.size() > 0) {

                    mScaleFactors.set(mScaleFactors.size() - 1, Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(detector.getScaleFactor() * mScaleFactors.get(mScaleFactors.size() - 1), 5.0f)));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mRotationDetector = new RotationGestureDetector(this, new RotationGestureDetector.OnRotationGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector) {
                if (mRotationThetas.size() > 0) {
                    mRotationThetas.set(mRotationThetas.size() - 1, (mRotationThetas.get(mRotationThetas.size() - 1) + (rotationDetector.getAngle() * -0.001f)));
                }
            }
        });
        // Set up tap listener.
        gestureDetector =
                new GestureDetector(
                        this,
                        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                                onSingleTap(e);
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                                if (e2.getPointerCount() == 1 && mTranslationX.size() > 0 && mTranslationZ.size() > 0) {

                                    double angle = findCameraAngleFromOrigin();
                                    double speed = 0.001d;

                                    if (angle / 90d < 1) //Quadrant 1
                                    {
                                        double transX = -(distanceY * (angle / 90d)) + (distanceX * ((90d - angle) / 90d));
                                        double transY = (distanceY * ((90d - angle) / 90d)) + (distanceX * (angle / 90d));
//                        showSnackbarMessage("ANGLE: " + angle + ", distanceX: " + distanceX + ", distanceY: " + distanceY, false);
                                        mTranslationX.set(mTranslationX.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationX.get(mTranslationX.size() - 1) + (transX * -speed)));
                                        mTranslationZ.set(mTranslationZ.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationZ.get(mTranslationZ.size() - 1) + (transY * -speed)));
                                    } else if (angle / 90d < 2) //Quadrant 2
                                    {
                                        angle -= 90d;
                                        double transX = (distanceX * (angle / 90d)) + (distanceY * ((90d - angle) / 90d));
                                        double transY = (-distanceX * ((90d - angle) / 90d)) + (distanceY * (angle / 90d));
//                        showSnackbarMessage("ANGLE: " + angle + ", distanceX: " + distanceX + ", distanceY: " + distanceY, false);
                                        mTranslationX.set(mTranslationX.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationX.get(mTranslationX.size() - 1) + (transX * speed)));
                                        mTranslationZ.set(mTranslationZ.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationZ.get(mTranslationZ.size() - 1) + (transY * speed)));
                                    } else if (angle / 90d < 3) //Quadrant 3
                                    {
                                        angle -= 180d;
                                        double transX = (distanceY * (angle / 90d)) + (-distanceX * ((90d - angle) / 90d));
                                        double transY = (-distanceY * ((90d - angle) / 90d)) + (-distanceX * (angle / 90d));
//                        showSnackbarMessage("ANGLE: " + angle + ", distanceX: " + distanceX + ", distanceY: " + distanceY, false);
                                        mTranslationX.set(mTranslationX.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationX.get(mTranslationX.size() - 1) + (transX * -speed)));
                                        mTranslationZ.set(mTranslationZ.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationZ.get(mTranslationZ.size() - 1) + (transY * -speed)));
                                    } else  //Quadrant 4
                                    {
                                        angle -= 270d;
                                        double transX = (-distanceX * (angle / 90d)) + (-distanceY * ((90d - angle) / 90d));
                                        double transY = (distanceX * ((90d - angle) / 90d)) + (-distanceY * (angle / 90d));
//                        showSnackbarMessage("ANGLE: " + angle + ", distanceX: " + distanceX + ", distanceY: " + distanceY, false);
                                        mTranslationX.set(mTranslationX.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationX.get(mTranslationX.size() - 1) + (transX * speed)));
                                        mTranslationZ.set(mTranslationZ.size() - 1, (float) (mTranslationZ.get(mTranslationZ.size() - 1) + (transY * speed)));
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                }

                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        });

        surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(
                new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        boolean retVal = mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        if (retVal)
                            mRotationDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        retVal = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) || retVal;
                        return retVal || gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        //return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                });

        // Set up renderer.
        surfaceView.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
        surfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        surfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); // Alpha used for plane blending.
        surfaceView.setRenderer(this);
        surfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

        installRequested = false;
    }

    private double findCameraAngleFromOrigin() {
        double angle = getDegree(mCurrentCameraMatrix[2], mCurrentCameraMatrix[0]) -
                getDegree(mOriginCameraMatrix[2], mOriginCameraMatrix[0]);
        if (angle < 0)
            return angle + 360;
        return angle;
    }

    private double getDegree(double value1, double value2) {
        double firstAngle = value1 * 90;
        double secondAngle = value2 * 90;
        if (secondAngle >= 0 && firstAngle >= 0) {
            return firstAngle; // first quadrant
        } else if (secondAngle < 0 && firstAngle >= 0) {
            return 90 + (90 - firstAngle); //second quadrant
        } else if (secondAngle < 0 && firstAngle < 0) {
            return 180 - firstAngle; //third quadrant
        } else {
            return 270 + (90 + firstAngle); //fourth quadrant
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (session == null) {
            Exception exception = null;
            String message = null;
            try {
                switch (ArCoreApk.getInstance().requestInstall(this, !installRequested)) {
                    case INSTALL_REQUESTED:
                        installRequested = true;
                        return;
                    case INSTALLED:
                        break;
                }

                // ARCore requires camera permissions to operate. If we did not yet obtain runtime
                // permission on Android M and above, now is a good time to ask the user for it.
                if (!CameraPermissionHelper.hasCameraPermission(this)) {
                    CameraPermissionHelper.requestCameraPermission(this);
                    return;
                }

                session = new Session(/* context= */ this);
            } catch (UnavailableArcoreNotInstalledException
                    | UnavailableUserDeclinedInstallationException e) {
                message = "Please install ARCore";
                exception = e;
            } catch (UnavailableApkTooOldException e) {
                message = "Please update ARCore";
                exception = e;
            } catch (UnavailableSdkTooOldException e) {
                message = "Please update this app";
                exception = e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                message = "This device does not support AR";
                exception = e;
            }

            if (message != null) {
                showSnackbarMessage(message, true);
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception creating session", exception);
                return;
            }

            // Create default config and check if supported.
            Config config = new Config(session);
            if (!session.isSupported(config)) {
                showSnackbarMessage("This device does not support AR", true);
            }
            session.configure(config);
        }

        showLoadingMessage();
        // Note that order matters - see the note in onPause(), the reverse applies here.
        session.resume();
        surfaceView.onResume();
        displayRotationHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (session != null) {
            // Note that the order matters - GLSurfaceView is paused first so that it does not try
            // to query the session. If Session is paused before GLSurfaceView, GLSurfaceView may
            // still call session.update() and get a SessionPausedException.
            displayRotationHelper.onPause();
            surfaceView.onPause();
            session.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] results) {
        if (!CameraPermissionHelper.hasCameraPermission(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission is needed to run this application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            if (!CameraPermissionHelper.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this)) {
                // Permission denied with checking "Do not ask again".
                CameraPermissionHelper.launchPermissionSettings(this);
            }
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            // Standard Android full-screen functionality.
            getWindow()
                    .getDecorView()
                    .setSystemUiVisibility(
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }

    private void onSingleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        // Queue tap if there is space. Tap is lost if queue is full.
        queuedSingleTaps.offer(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);

        // Create the texture and pass it to ARCore session to be filled during update().
        backgroundRenderer.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/ this);

        // Prepare the other rendering objects.
        try {
            virtualObject.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/ this, "andy.obj", "andy.png");
            virtualObject.setMaterialProperties(0.0f, 3.5f, 1.0f, 6.0f);
            virtualObjectShadow.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/ this, "andy_shadow.obj", "andy_shadow.png");
            virtualObjectShadow.setBlendMode(BlendMode.Shadow);
            virtualObjectShadow.setMaterialProperties(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read obj file");
        }
        try {
            planeRenderer.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/ this, "trigrid.png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read plane texture");
        }
        pointCloud.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/ this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        displayRotationHelper.onSurfaceChanged(width, height);
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        mVirtualObjects.add(virtualObject);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Clear screen to notify driver it should not load any pixels from previous frame.
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Notify ARCore session that the view size changed so that the perspective matrix and
        // the video background can be properly adjusted.
        displayRotationHelper.updateSessionIfNeeded(session);
        try {
            session.setCameraTextureName(backgroundRenderer.getTextureId());

            // Obtain the current frame from ARSession. When the configuration is set to
            // UpdateMode.BLOCKING (it is by default), this will throttle the rendering to the
            // camera framerate.
            Frame frame = session.update();
            Camera camera = frame.getCamera();

            // Handle taps. Handling only one tap per frame, as taps are usually low frequency
            // compared to frame rate.

            MotionEvent tap = queuedSingleTaps.poll();
            if (tap != null && camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                for (HitResult hit : frame.hitTest(tap)) {
                    // Check if any plane was hit, and if it was hit inside the plane polygon
                    Trackable trackable = hit.getTrackable();
                    // Creates an anchor if a plane or an oriented point was hit.
                    if ((trackable instanceof Plane && ((Plane) trackable).isPoseInPolygon(hit.getHitPose()))
                            || (trackable instanceof Point
                            && ((Point) trackable).getOrientationMode()
                            == OrientationMode.ESTIMATED_SURFACE_NORMAL)) {
                        // Hits are sorted by depth. Consider only closest hit on a plane or oriented point.
                        // Cap the number of objects created. This avoids overloading both the
                        // rendering system and ARCore.
                        if (mAnchors.size() >= 20)
                        {
                            //Alert the user that the maximum has been reached, must call from
                            //Handler as this is a UI action being done on a worker thread.
                            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void handleMessage(Message message)
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(HelloArActivity.this,
                                            "You've reached the maximum!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            };

                            // Alternatively, you can start detaching, however, a revision to the
                            // mAnchorReferences and mScalingFactors should be made!
                            // mAnchors.get(0).detach();
                            // mAnchors.remove(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Adding an Anchor tells ARCore that it should track this position in
                            // space. This anchor is created on the Plane to place the 3d model
                            // in the correct position relative both to the world and to the plane.
                            mScaleFactors.add(1.0f);
                            Anchor anchor = hit.createAnchor();
                            mAnchors.add(anchor);
                            mAnchorReferences.add(mCurrent);
                            camera.getDisplayOrientedPose().toMatrix(mOriginCameraMatrix, 0);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Draw background.
            backgroundRenderer.draw(frame);

            // If not tracking, don't draw 3d objects.
            if (camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.PAUSED) {
                return;
            }

            // Get projection matrix.
            float[] projmtx = new float[16];
            camera.getProjectionMatrix(projmtx, 0, 0.1f, 100.0f);

            // Get camera matrix and draw.
            float[] viewmtx = new float[16];
            camera.getViewMatrix(viewmtx, 0);

            // Compute lighting from average intensity of the image.
            final float lightIntensity = frame.getLightEstimate().getPixelIntensity();

            // Visualize tracked points.
            PointCloud pointCloud = frame.acquirePointCloud();
            this.pointCloud.update(pointCloud);
            this.pointCloud.draw(viewmtx, projmtx);

            // Application is responsible for releasing the point cloud resources after
            // using it.
            pointCloud.release();

            // Check if we detected at least one plane. If so, hide the loading message.
            if (messageSnackbar != null) {
                for (Plane plane : session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
                    if (plane.getType() == com.google.ar.core.Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING
                            && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                        hideLoadingMessage();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            camera.getDisplayOrientedPose().toMatrix(mCurrentCameraMatrix, 0);

            // Visualize planes.
            planeRenderer.drawPlanes(
                    session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class), camera.getDisplayOrientedPose(), projmtx);

            // Visualize anchors created by touch.
            int ac = 0;

            for (Anchor anchor : mAnchors) {
                if (anchor.getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                    continue;
                }
                // Get the current pose of an Anchor in world space. The Anchor pose is updated
                // during calls to session.update() as ARCore refines its estimate of the world.
                anchor.getPose().toMatrix(anchorMatrix, 0);
                if (mScaleFactors.size() <= ac) {
                    mScaleFactors.add(1.0f);
                }
                if (mRotationThetas.size() <= ac) {
                    mRotationThetas.add(0.0f);
                }
                if (mTranslationX.size() <= ac) {
                    mTranslationX.add(viewmtx[3]);
                }
                if (mTranslationZ.size() <= ac) {
                    mTranslationZ.add(viewmtx[11]);
                }

                translateMatrix(mTranslationX.get(ac), 0, mTranslationZ.get(ac));
                rotateYAxisMatrix(mRotationThetas.get(ac));

                // Update and draw the model and its shadow.
                ObjectRenderer vitualObject = mVirtualObjects.get(mAnchorReferences.get(ac));
                vitualObject.updateModelMatrix(anchorMatrix, mScaleFactors.get(ac));
                vitualObject.draw(viewmtx, projmtx, lightIntensity);


            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // Avoid crashing the application due to unhandled exceptions.
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception on the OpenGL thread", t);
        }
    }

    private void rotateYAxisMatrix(float rotationTheta) {
        if (rotationTheta != 0.0f) {
            anchorMatrix[0] = (float) Math.cos(rotationTheta);
            anchorMatrix[2] = (float) Math.sin(rotationTheta);
            anchorMatrix[5] = 1;
            anchorMatrix[8] = -(float) Math.sin(rotationTheta);
            anchorMatrix[10] = (float) Math.cos(rotationTheta);
            anchorMatrix[15] = 1;
        }
    }

    private void translateMatrix(float xDistance, float yDistance, float zDistance) {
        Matrix.translateM(anchorMatrix, 0, xDistance, yDistance, zDistance);
    }
```

Comment: This is just the code I put, so not really an answer. I realize you're probably missing this class btw:
https://github.com/nominedisorder/arcore-example/blob/master/RotationGestureDetector.java.

Comment: actually am already having RotationGestureDetector.java class . this is not a pblm.// 
                ObjectRenderer vitualObject = mVirtualObjects.get(mAnchorReferences.get(ac)); how to add file.obj into mVirtualObjects(Array List)..am adding file.obj like this.// virtualObject.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/ this, "andy.obj", "andy.png");
            virtualObject.setMaterialProperties(0.0f, 3.5f, 1.0f, 6.0f);//   @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
      
        mVirtualObjects.add(virtualObject);
    }

Comment: my problem was the file.obj not added into mVirtualObjects array list. can you provide that code.. how to add mVirtualObjects.add(virtualobject);

Comment: It's as simple as:
ObjectRenderer virtualObject = new ObjectRenderer();
                virtualObject.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/this, path, model);
                virtualObject.setMaterialProperties(0.0f, 3.5f, 1.0f, 6.0f);
                mVirtualObjects.add(virtualObject);

But I modified my ObjectRenderer to allow for proper .OBJ files with .TGA images based on this example:
https://github.com/JohnLXiang/arcore-sandbox/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/rendering/ObjectRenderer.java

Comment: thanks above code its working.. multiple object add by clicked position, but I need know how to load different object when clicked particular item from the list.